# How to print text from one client to all other clients using Sockets

Tags: java, multithreading, sockets

Everytime I connect a client to the server, it adds a new socket to my ArrayList. When I send a message in my client to the server, it shows up in the server output window, but I am trying to push the message that it sent from one client thread into all of the client windows by somehow iterating through the ArrayList of Sockets.

How would I go about sending the input from one of the clients to all of the clients?

I have the program broken up into 3 classes, Client, Server, and Service.

Comment: I'm curious how much have you tried? Your already very close to doing it, you already explained how it's going to be done (which is the right way) have you tried anything yet? I think you should give yourself a chance to solve it without help. Imo

Comment: I have tried many different ways of iterating through the arraylist, and then doing an out.println(input) to each socket, but none of those worked. Also I am getting errors, rightly so, because my arrayList is not in the same class as the printwriters, so I'm not fully comprehending how to output to all clients when the printwriter is in the service class, and its a new service everytime a client is opened. I deleted all my code because it was always wrong.

Comment: Ok here's a few hints... instead of just saving the sockets. You could encapsulate a logged on user in a lets call it "miniserver" class. You could include their input and output streams as field values instead of their sockets and use the outputstream to send information to all of them in a for each/other loop. If you didn't know you can use "ObjectOutputStream" and "ObjectInputStream" to send objects over sockets. Meaning you could fx make a "Message" class and send that object over the stream.

Comment: I haven't used scanners or printwriters before when working with sockets... but using the printstream should technically work. I know it works with objectoutput/inputstreams though. I mixed something up, your service class is basically the miniserver class I was talking about.

Comment: Well you could make you service class an inner class I suppose... that way it would always have access to your servers field values and thereby the arraylist. Basically just copy paste it right before the last curly bracket in your service class.

Comment: Lol I'm rambling plz ignore me ill drop an answer in a sec just need to look at your code once more.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So basically just make the arraylist an arraylist of the Service class and add that object to the arraylist instead of the socket.

Then in the server class you iterate over the services and use the printstream (not the socket) to send data to all the logged in clients.

Comment: I havent tested anything, but if this doesn't work by itself. You might have to work on the code in your doService method.

Comment: changing the ArrayList to be of Services has helped alot, I am way on my way now. Went a different route i think but stayed very close to what you were saying.

Comment: I am having one last problem now, I will upload my new code now,

I have a problem when I iterate through the services, i call a service.printMessage, which calls out.println(input).

My problem is that out.println is equal to PrintWriter(s.getOutputStream). So the only client that input has any value in is the actual client that submitted text. The other sockets dont have a value for s.getOutputStream, so when i call out.println(input) they dont print anything because that socket doesnt have text.

Comment: I noticed something else in your service class, you can't compare strings with == you need to use <string>.equals(<other string>). Minor detail but important if u want quit etc. to work. I'm still re-reading your current problem and trying to understand it.

Comment: Ok now I see where your confusion lies. Your trying to call the message on the server through the service... don't think this way. Like you have it set up now on your server, listening to incoming users and saving them so they are logged in. You need another loop aswell, which listens after messages. Like you have in your handleMessage() method... that part shouldnt be a method it should be something thats running in parallel with your other loop. So you need to use threads here to make it work.

Comment: Your services should never be trying to do something outside of itself, instead your server should get the information it needs or send the information it needs to send through the services. A smart move here would be implementing the runnable interface in the service class OR extend the Thread class. In other words "all your stored services should each be a thread that's running by itself". This is why I used the term miniserver earlier.

Comment: My Service class already implements the Runnable interface, how else would i use that to help me?

Comment: You need to handle messages directly in you service class... it kinda needs to be a tiny chat server itself. You can't handle the messages through your server class. There's a message listenig loop missing in your run() method. Without it your clients will never receive any messages.

Comment: Think of it like this 1) server listens 2) client connects and server stores the client (service) 3) client sends a message to server 4) server gets the message and sends it to everyone in the service list. In actuality the clients are never talking to each other, the server receives all messages and forwards them between users (if its private chat) or to everyone (general chat).

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/51841/discussion-between-obedmarsh-and-webminer07)

Comment: The way you just described it, is how I thought it was currently written. I believed it to be: Server waits for connections from clients, client connects, the client sends msg, the server grabs msg using getInput, and sends it to all clients via, print message.

I literally think the code is working because I am getting the input to appear in the other client windows, but it will only show up if i type a message first and hit enter in the window.

So if I have 3 clients open. I type '1' in first, the other windows will not print out '1' unless i type a message first and hit enter. is this

Comment: where the listening while loop you were talking about comes into play?

Comment: Go to the chat link I posted were not allowed to write too much in here.